# Calculating percentage change of a metric for a group in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table as follows:

```
  id   | timestamp  |     agentid     |       input_interface       | sourceipv4address | totalbytes_sum
-------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------+----------------
 10733 | 1593648000 | 203.121.214.129 | 203.121.214.129 interface 1 | 10.10.10.10       |           3857
 10734 | 1593648000 | 203.121.214.129 | 203.121.214.129 interface 1 | 10.10.10.101      |          45960
 10731 | 1593648600 | 203.121.214.129 | 203.121.214.129 interface 1 | 10.10.10.10       |          20579
 10736 | 1593648600 | 203.121.214.129 | 203.121.214.129 interface 1 | 10.10.10.101      |          21384
 10737 | 1593648600 | 203.121.214.129 | 203.121.214.129 interface 1 | 10.10.10.107      |           2094
```

This table is populated by taking samples from a network every 10 minutes. Basically I am trying to build a view to calculate the percentage change on totalbytes_sum for each group (agentid,input_interface,sourceipv4address) and show it as:

```
timestamp | agentid | input_interface | sourceipv4address | totalbytes_sum | percent
```

The calculation needs to happen based on the current 10 minute and the previous 10 minute. i can guarantee that there will be only one copy of a particular agentid,input_interface,sourceipv4address combination within the same 10 minutes.

If a combination did not happen to have a record within the previous 10 minutes, the percentage will be +%100.

I was trying to apply the Partition/Order logic but had no luck. the offset function seems good too but I am pretty much stuck.

Can someone please assist me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timestamps are all the same.   I assume they would be ~600 seconds apart in your actual data.

Please try something like this and let me know in comments if it does not work for you or if you need explanation for any of it:

```
select timestamp, agentid, input_interface, 
       sourceipv4address, totalbytes_sum,
       timestamp - lag(timestamp) over w as elapsed_time,  -- illustration column
       lag(totalbytes_sum) over w as last_totalbytes_sum,  -- illustration column
       case
         when coalesce(lag(timestamp) over w, 0) = 0 then 100.0
         when timestamp - lag(timestamp) over w > 600 then 100.0
         else 100.0 * (totalbytes_sum - (lag(totalbytes_sum) over w)) / 
                        (lag(totalbytes_sum) over w)
       end as percent
  from sample_table
window w as (partition by agentid, input_interface, sourceipv4address
                 order by timestamp)
;
```